# Different layer LineString datatypes

Tags: qgis, layers, merge

Trying to merge 2 vector layers; one is of type "LineStingZ", the other is just "LineString".  When I run the merge algorithm I get the message saying "Error executing algorithm Merge vector layers All layers must have same geometry type!"; but when I try to do a save-as on the LineString layer and check the 'Include z-dimension' I get a new "LineStringZM" type and they still don't match.  Is there another way to specify the layer type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the MMQGIS plugin to convert your LineStringZ layer to LineString. From the MMQGIS menu go to Modify > Convert Geometry Type. Select your LineStringZ layer as the source layer and new geometry type as lines.

EDIT: As pointed out by @Alexandre Neto, in QGIS 2.18, Convert geometry type is available from the processing toolbox under QGIS geoalgorithms > Vector geometry tools.

Comment: In QGIS 2.18 you don't need MMQGIS plugin for that. the Convert Geometry type is available on the Processing toolbox.

Comment: You're right @Alexandre Neto- I hadn't noticed that. Under QGIS geoalgorithms > Vector geometry tools.

Comment: Thanks - that works.  Also works just by doing a 'save as' and changing the geometry type from Automatic to LineSting and unchecking the 'Include Z-dimension'.    So to solve the issue in the end, I had to change the LineStingZ layer to LineString, I couldn't do it the other way around without getting the ZM LineSting type.  Thanks for the help!